# Error While Installing amazon-cloud-watch-agent through system manager

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch

I'm facing issue while installing amazon-cloud-watch-agent through AWS system manager.Error details as follows.

install errors: & : The term 'C:\Program Files\Amazon\AmazonCloudWatchAgent\amazon-cloudwatch-agent-ctl.ps1' is not recognized as the
name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was
included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At C:\ProgramData\Amazon\SSM\Packages_arnawsssmpackageamazoncloudwatchagent_2B_HP6ASKUGHXDL73H24T7UUUKNWXRDTKWGMMX5YMX
LDHWGQE2KUPXA====\1.247357.0b252275\install.ps1:23 char:3

- & "${Cmd}" -Action cond-restart
- ```
  + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Program File...h-agent-ctl.ps1:String) [], ParentContainsErrorRecord
  ```

Exception
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

failed to run commands: exit status 1
Failed to install package; install status Failed

I have tried install it manually.It also didn't work.

Comment: Issue Resolved by Reinstalling Power shell.

Answer (score 0):

Download and install amazon cloudwatch agent for windows from link:

https://s3.amazonaws.com/amazoncloudwatch-agent/windows/amd64/latest/amazon-cloudwatch-agent.msi

for any other OS follow the link:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/install-CloudWatch-Agent-commandline-fleet.html

After this run your command.

Comment: Error is occurred while installing the agent and the setup is downloaded from https://s3.amazonaws.com/amazoncloudwatch-agent/windows/amd64/latest/amazon-cloudwatch-agent.msi itself.

Comment: What error? could you add details.